# find lowest value and pop from multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, min

I've three lists and I want to find the lowest value in all of these three lists.
I've done this with this code:

```
    list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    list2 = [1,5,6,7,8]
    list3 = [7,8,9,10,11]

    lowestnumber = min(min(list1), min(list2), min(list3))
```

The result is `1`, which is good, but now I want to pop this value from list1 or list2, it doesn't matter which list.

What I tried is to `zip(list1, list2, list3)` but then I don't know anymore to which list it belongs to.

Does anyone know a Pythonic way to pop the lowest number value from `list1` or `list2`?

Comment: Are the lists always sorted?

Comment: Yes, I use list.sort(key=int)

Comment: Do you need the lists to be sorted for something else? otherwise it might be more efficient not to sort them at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your lists are sorted you can select the **minimum list** and then pop the first item from that list:

```
mn = min(list1, list2, list3, key=min).pop(0)
print mn
# 1
```

The item has been poppped from `list1` in this case:

```
print list1, list2, list3
# [2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 5, 6, 7, 8] [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: If you're using the fact the lists are sorted, why not `min(list1,list2,list3)[0]` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands They want to **pop**

Comment: @COLDSPEED Also seems to work without the key=min since the lists are already sorted

Comment: Ok sure, I missed that thanks, by why the `key` as coldspeed said?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It is not exactly needed. But going by what I've experienced in the past, sorting of lists may not come as inituitive first hand; doesn't hurt to be a little redundant. They might as well remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use itertools' chain

```
from itertools import chain
lowestnumber = min(chain(list1,list2,list3))
```

Comment: OP's issue is the `pop`ping, not finding the min

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to iterate over all 3 lists because you wouldn't know the minimum location beforehand:

```
from itertools import chain

lst = [list1, list2, list3]
lowestnumber = min(chain(*lst))

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if mn in lst[i]:
        lst[i].remove(mn)
        break
```

This solution would work for arbitrary number of lists and doesn't require them to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

More possible solutions:
1. Merge lists into a single one first.
2. Find a min for each list, then find a min among them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if he needs to still have 3 different lists, then your sollution may be incorrect.